# Merging Cells in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a database which contains 5 tables. Each table contains 24 rows and each row contains 4 columns.

I want to display these records in Excel sheet. The heading of each table is the name of the table, but I am unable to merge the columns for heading.

Please help me.

Answer (score 79):

Using the Interop you get a range of cells and call the `.Merge()` method on that range.

```
eWSheet.Range[eWSheet.Cells[1, 1], eWSheet.Cells[4, 1]].Merge();
```

Comment: you are missing a parameter- you can put inside `Type.Missing`

Comment: Agreed. `Range.Merge( object across )`, though in practice the argument can be a bool.  If true, merge cells in each row of the specified range as separate merged cells.  If false or `Type.Missing`, merge all cells.

Answer (score 12):

```
oSheet.get_Range("A1", "AS1").Merge();
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorkshe et);

Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

ws.Cells[1,1] = "Testing";

Excel.Range range = ws.get_Range(ws.Cells[1,1],ws.Cells[1,2]);

range.Merge(true);

range.Interior.ColorIndex =36;

xl.Visible =true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Code Snippet

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Excel.Application excelApp = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        excelApp.get_Range("A1:A360,B1:E1", Type.Missing).Merge(Type.Missing);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        excelApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application ;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel:

`worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum], worksheet.Cells[rowNum, columnNum]].Merge();`

You can also use NPOI:

```
var cellsTomerge = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(firstrow, lastrow, firstcol, lastcol);
_sheet.AddMergedRegion(cellsTomerge);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solves the issue in the appropriate way

```
// Merge a row
            ws.Cell("B2").Value = "Merged Row(1) of Range (B2:D3)";
            ws.Range("B2:D3").Row(1).Merge();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NPOI to do it.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
Cell cell = row.createCell((short) 1);
cell.setCellValue("This is a test of merging");

sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
        1, //first row (0-based)
        1, //last row  (0-based)
        1, //first column (0-based)
        2  //last column  (0-based)
));

// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
ws.Range("A1:F2").Merge();
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer as that from C Ross

Answer (score 0):

take a list of string as like

```
List<string> colValListForValidation = new List<string>();
```

and match string before the task. it will help you bcz all merge cells will have same value

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheet["YourRange"].Merge();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: What is the YourRange means Range is int i guess not string

Answer (score 0):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
// Your code...
yourWorksheet.Range[yourWorksheet.Cells[rowBegin,colBegin], yourWorksheet.Cells[yourWorksheet.rowEnd, colEnd]].Merge();
```

Row and Col start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution would be with **.Merge()** method.

- X - cell letter
- Y - cell number

```
ws.Range["XY:XY"].Merge();
```