# Create EXCEL from html table using C#

Tags: c#, html, excel, export, html-table

I am trying to create an excel sheet for shipping products using C# and HTML table. The image shown below is my HTML as it looks in the browser. What I am trying to do it to take this table and shove it into an excel page keeping proportions and merges intact. (I put a border color on each td to symbolise the cells in excel, that color wont be necessary once it's in Excel sheet).

[image: HTML Table shown in browser]

I tried working from this post ([How to export html table to excel using asp.net/c#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1573064.aspx/1)) but when using this code my table hasnt become cells when its in the file, its just one cell with text in it.

[image: Excel sheet]

To be added, when using the code on that link i took a copy of the code in the aspx page and put it as a html string which was then added to the form, as shown in the example on the link. This then produced the same form that I had previously made by hand.

```
var html = "<tabe><tr><td width=\"86\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"91\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"139\">x</td><td width=\"93\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td><td width=\"72\">x</td></tr><tr><td rowspan=\"5\" colspan=\"2\" style=\"border: solid 2px black;\">INVOICE</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td rowspan=\"2\" colspan=\"2\" style=\"background-color: green;\">Ref</td><td></td><td style=\"background-color: green;\">Swiss Post</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td style=\"background-color: yellow;\">SoBling</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i would suggest you to make DataTable, save your entrys from html into it. dish in data into excell, and format cells merges/colors/sizes etc.

Comment: Do you have an example of how i could set column width, row height and perform cell merges using datatable?

Comment: you cant in datatable, but when you export dataTable into the Excell you can format cells directly there i.e. merge: eWSheet.Range[eWSheet.Cells[1, 1], eWSheet.Cells[4, 1]].Merge();

Answer (score 0):

I made you a few links that will help you with merging, width, height and creating Excell. I have made links only refering SO that should work togeather.

[creating simple excel sheet in c# with strings as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100901/creating-simple-excel-sheet-in-c-sharp-with-strings-as-input)

[Merging Cells in Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532199/merging-cells-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

[.net c# excel column AutoFit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345396/net-c-sharp-excel-column-autofit)

[excel cell coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897062/excel-cell-coloring)

width and heigth are 'same'. I havent dish out you a solution in terms on code, rather the links so you make your own solution and learn from it. Ask if you have questions.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using epplus for creating excel charts

(previously http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
now available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus)

Answer (score -1):

var html = "<td width="86">x<td width="72">x<td width="91">x<td width="72">x<td width="72">x<td width="139">x<td width="93">x<td width="72">x<td width="72">x<td width="72">x<td width="72">x<td width="72">x<td rowspan="5" colspan="2" style="border: solid 2px black;">INVOICE<td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background-color: green;">Ref<td style="background-color: green;">Swiss Post<td style="background-color: yellow;">SoBling";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).